# Upper bound to 1234......n in base n+1

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

I'm interested in knowing whether there is a non-trivial upper bound to the number $1234....n$ (a number consist of the digits, MSDigit-->LSDigit: $1,2,3,4,5,6,.....,n-1,n$), in base $n+1$.

By non-trivial I mean not $n^n$. if one found - what is the lowest one?

For example, look at 12345(base 6), which is 1865.

My guess is that it's indeed about $n^n$, but I have no proof or anything..

I'm searching for a good upper-bound in order to know how many bits are needed in order to save a number between ($0-1234....n$) in terms of $n$, when $n$ is already known.

If you can find a good upper-bound to the same number as above $+1$ (its digits are: $1,2,3,4,....,n-2,n,0$, or $12350_{n+1}=1866$ if we continue the last example), still in $base_{n+1}$. This is the number of possible numbers between $0-1234....n$) and it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: $(1234\dots n)_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}-(n+1)^2 + n}{n^2}$ (ref: [OEIS A023811](https://oeis.org/A023811))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact value is $\dfrac{\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1} - 1}{n}-1}{n}-1 = \dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1} - 1-n-n^2}{n^2}$

which is $\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^2} - 1$ rounded down when $n \ge 2$

This is between $n^{n-1}$ and $n^n$ when $n \ge 4$

It is almost [OEIS A023811](https://oeis.org/A023811), which instead uses base $n$ and $1234\ldots(n-1)_{(n)}$, if you want more information

Comment: A consequence I find amusing in a strange way is that $\left(\left(t^{t^{t^0}}-t^0\right)/\left(t^{t^0}-{t^0}\right) - {t^0}\right)/\left(t^{t^0}-{t^0}\right) - {t^0}=123456789$ when $t=10$

Comment: A pretty good asymptotic then would be $en^{n-1}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, though that a lower bound, while say  $3.04n^{n-1}$ is an upper bound